# Django-Dynamic Form Increment ID for each new input element added in formset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-forms

I have a form which takes 4 fields as input as below:-

**forms.py**

```
AuthorFormset = modelformset_factory(
    Author,
    fields=('due_date','author' ),
    extra=5,
    widgets={'due_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Date'}),
            'author': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'txtSearch',
            'placeholder': 'Participants'
        }),
    }
```

I have added a css ID to field author which is a Text input.
To this text input I am also conducting an Ajax call through Jquery Autocomplete feature.

**view.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
<div class="row form-row spacer">
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.author}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
          source: "/ajax_calls/search/",
          minLength: 2,
          open: function(){
              setTimeout(function () {
                  $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 99);
              }, 0);
          }
        });

  });

</script>
```

Everything is working fine its just that I am only able to handle Ajax call of only the first field.
**I want to increment ID for each new field added in dynamic forms.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of incrementing id, you can also loop on each field in jquery, using `.each()`, for example on each input with type attribute `<input type="text" ...>` :

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
   var $input = $(this);
   $input.autocomplete({
      source: "/ajax_calls/search/",
      minLength: 2,
      open: function(){
         ...
      }
   });
});
```

**References :** 
https://api.jquery.com/each/

EDIT : missing ending bracket in jquery selector

Comment: There are various other, input tags as well which are same as text field

Comment: Can this be done in a more precised way like to a particular text field in entire form on the basis of unique placeholder value or name value of that text field??

Comment: If there are other text fields, you can discriminate them by adding a special class to the input, adding it in the `'author'`  TextInput widget, modifying attribute `attrs` from `'class': 'form-control'` to `'class': 'form-control author-input'`, then modifying the jquery selector (currently `'input[type="text"'`) to `'.author-input'`

Comment: To answer your second question, selector in jquery can select almost anything you can identify. For example, based on name attribute, you can use `$('input[name="value-your-looking-for"]')`

Comment: @ChiragSharma - Are you getting any warning in the **console** about `Non-Unique IDs`?